# 11.04 unable to read DVDs and CDs burned in 11.04?

Tags: dvd, burning

I'm noticing all of my computers with Natty cannot read DVDs that I have burned using Natty. Does anyone else have this problem? I can put the DVD or CD into a Maverick system and it will read the disc. But Natty systems I have cannot read anything I've burned using Natty.

Comment: Unfortunately, Answer #1 did not help me. While in 11.04 I had used K3B to burn the data disc, which has never given me problems before. If the below tip did not help, I dont know what it could be.

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been encountered by other Natty users and has been fixed with the following two commands.

1. Open the Accessories;Terminal and enter the following command to get greater CD support:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
   ```
2. Next enter this second command to enable greater DVD support:

   ```
   sudo /usr/share/doc/libdvdread4/install-css.sh
   ```